# How to use a mask ip address in firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy

In IE, I can say to not use a proxy when the ip adress is: 10.*

If I do the same in Firefox it doesn't work. It uses the proxy when I access a 10.** site.

How can I make Firefox don't use the proxy with a mask like IE?

Comment: I've found the answer, but I didn't want to use a proxy addon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.1/999 is not a sensible IP range.  I am answering this because at some point this will stop working if firefox validates the IP ranges better in the future.  It is possible that 10.1/999 is not matching *all* of the 10 subnet anyway.

To exclude all of the 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 range, use

```
10.0.0.0/8
```

The 8 means "match any address where the first 8 bits are the same".  As an IP address is comprised of 4 x 8 bit octets, 8 means the first octet.

So the following

```
10.0.0.0/16
```

means "match the first two octets" and so would match 10.0.0.0-10.0.255.255.  I

So it follows that 10.1/999 is meaningless.  It is saying match the first 999 bits of 10.1.0.0.  Given that an IP address is only 32 bits long, it is likely that this is working through a bug rather than intended behaviour.

Comment: thanks m8! How can I exclude the following in firefox: *.montepio.pt

Comment: ```.montepio.pt```  Note the preceding dot.

Comment: yes, for example: abc.montepio.pt, 123.montepio.pt, etc.. How can I mask these?

Comment: The ```.montepio.pt``` in the exclusions list means ```*.montepio.pt```. ```montepio.pt``` would only exclude the main domain.